# ember.js show store data in template

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have JSON data I am retrieving from a server and I want to show it in a template in ember.js. I have data saved in the store and I want to render the data in the template.

My template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="DieDaten" >
<p>{{name}} some text2</p>

 <ul id="todo-list">
 {{#each person in model}}
        <li>
          <label>{{person.firstName}} and text</label>
        </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>

 <button id="clear-completed" {{action 'click'}}>
    Submit
  </button>

</script>
```

and my associated controller

```
App.DieDatenController = Ember.Controller.extend({ 

   model: function () {
     return this.store.all('person');
   }

});
```

When the page loads, I get this.

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {
    return this.store.all('person');
  }
```

How do I fix this so it works?

Is there a simpler/better way to render the JSON in the template besides saving to the store, then rendering the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model` is not supported in `Ember.Controller` it is rather a part of `Ember.Route`. So, you're code should be:

```
App.DieDatenRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 

  model: function () {
    return this.store.all('person');
  }

});
```

You can read more about specifying a route's model at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/